# What does "immediately completes normally" mean for the if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, break, java-11

Does "immediately completes normally" mean that the if-statement is in fact  bypassed and its condition is not evaluated?

**EDIT:**

I intentially have omitted an example that to understand the phrase iteself from the Java specification relative to the if-statement.

But it seems nobody even considered the phrase in this context.

So here is a demonstartive program.

```
import java.io.*;

class TestBreakWIthLabel
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int x = 1;

        L:if ( x++ < 2 ) break L;

        System.out.println( "x = " + x );
    }
}
```

But it is a bad idea that somebody will provide his "explanation" looking at the program. I want to know the meanung of the phrase independently of the program example.

Here is a correslonding quote from the Specification (14.15 The break Statement).

> A break statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control
>   to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; this  statement, which is called the break
>   target, then **immediately completes normally**. In this case, the
>   break target need not be a switch, while, do, or for statement.

Comment: Some (any?) context for this question would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [this part of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

> A `break` statement with `label Identifier` attempts to transfer control
>   to **the enclosing labeled statement** (§14.7) that has the same
>   `Identifier` as its `label`; this statement, which is called the `break`
>   target, then *immediately completes normally*. In this case, the `break`
>   target need not be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement.

where the `break` target is an `if` statement, then the enclosing labeled statement is the `if` statement and its condition has already been evaluated, since you're inside its body, its *contained Statement*. It's not evaluated again on *completion*.